# Application.persistenDataPath not working anymore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

Since yesterday evening my `Application.persistenDataPath` is not working anymore on one place in code. I am using it 2 times. On the first place it works on the second it doesnt work anymore...

Maybe a hint for you is, that I saved json very often yesterday. Also I had infinite loops what maybe caused the Application Settings to Crash.
On Android Build it is working fine. (I get the right Path on both usages)

*What I have tried below the code*

- Both in the same Class.
- Unity 2021.3.2f
- Using Google Firebase
- Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition

**This the code where it works:**
I am saving a Photo to the given Path.

```
//then Save To Disk as PNG
            byte[] bytes = avatarTexture.EncodeToPNG();
            var dirPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Resources/User/";
            if (!Directory.Exists(dirPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);
            }
            if (File.Exists(dirPath + "avatar" + ".png"))
            {
                File.Delete(dirPath + "avatar" + ".png");
            }
            File.WriteAllBytes(dirPath + "avatar" + ".png", bytes);

            saveUserDataAsJson(getUserToken(user.DisplayName, user.Email));
            _warningLoginText.text = "";
            _confirmLoginText.text = Translation.authManager_login_notification_loginSucceeded;
```

**This is the code where it does not work:**
I am saving a JSON File with User Information.

```
DataSnapshot snapshotYear = taskYear.Result;
_year = Convert.ToInt32(snapshotYear.Value);
FirebaseDatabaseUser tempUser = new FirebaseDatabaseUser(_token, _day, _month, _year);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tempUser);


Debug.Log("Can see it in Console");

//After pressing Play Button in Unity
//Editor i get no Debug outprint here
Debug.Log(Application.persistentDataPath);

var folderPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/Resources/User/";

Debug.Log("Can not see it in Console");
//HERE THE CODE STOPS AND NOTHING HAPPEN
//NO ERROR NO LOG NO FURTHER CODE WORKING
//HERE NOT WORKING ANYMORE



if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
}
if (File.Exists(folderPath + "userdata" + ".json"))
{
    File.Delete(folderPath + "userdata" + ".json");
}
File.WriteAllText(folderPath + "userdata" + ".json", json);
```

I have tried:

- rebuild Project Settings
- Print the Path in Console it was empty ""
- Cleaned GI Cache
- Restarted my PC
- Cloned the project new
- Tried using `Application.dataPath` (only for debugging tests, not to use it in my code) also not working in Unity Play Mode but on Android it points right to the APK.

First usage (Place in Code where it works) I get Path:
Computer: `C:\Users\{user}\AppData\LocalLow\{company}\{app}\Resources\User\`
Android: `.\Android\data\com.{company}.{app}\...\Resources\User\`

Second usage (Place in Code where does not work) I get Path:
Computer: ""
Android: "`.\Android\data\com.{company}.{app}\...\Resources\User\`"

I hope someone can explain the issue. I cannot solve the problem from myself. Need someone who has more background knowledge.

Comment: What does "works" mean and what happens when it does not work? Please read [mcve] and make sure you follow the link (near the end of that page) to the excellent page about debugging small programs.

Comment: dataPath and persistentDataPath point to different locations.  Maybe you are looking in the wrong place?

Comment: @AdrianHHH Hello thank you for your reply i edited my Question. Here:                
First usage (Place in Code where it works) i get Path:
Computer: "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\LocalLow\{company}\{app}\Resources\User\"
Android: ".\Android\data\com.{company}.{app}\...\Resources\User\"

Second usage (Place in Code where does not work) i get Path:
Computer: ""
Android: ".\Android\data\com.{company}.{app}\...\Resources\User\"

Comment: @hijinxbassist Hello thank you also for your fast reply. No i used Application.dataPath only for testing, because i wanted to check if the problem is in Application.persistentDataPath. But in Both Methods i get empty string "" on Unity Editor Play Mode. Didnt build it on Windows. The strange thing about this is, that on my first usage in the same Code file it works but in the second usage doesnt work anymore, but worked fine yesterday evening... Didn't really changed something.

Comment: The question is still not clear. What happens when it does not work? What does it do when it fails to work. What should it do when it works properly? Please [edit] the question to add more details and format them nicely; adding explanations in comments make them hard to read.

Comment: I have made some format and minot wording changes to the question. I hope I have done them correctly, if not then please [edit] it to correct my misunderstandings.

Comment: @AdrianHHH Thank you for your understanding and helping, not just voting Question down.

Comment: @AdrianHHH i added Debug Log in second Code Snippet. I get no Error or Exception. Code just stops working. In the Debug.Log() i added above you should see where the code stops.

Comment: Try using the "Application.dataPath()" method. It also saves resources locally.

Comment: @HouSheng-MSFT that wouldn't help as on Android this might be the path of the compressed APK .. `persistentDataPath` is the correct one to use in general

Comment: As a general hint: Don't construct your data paths over and over again.. not only is string concatenation inefficient but also this allows spelling mistakes and increases maintenance effort ... have a central `public static readonly string UserFolder = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, "Resources", "User");` and then use it to create your file paths **ONCE** as well `static readonly string AvatarPath = Path.Combine(UserFolder, "avatar.png");` and accordingly `static readonly string UserDataPath = Path.Combine(UserFolder, "userData.json");`

Comment: Is it possible that your second snippet is running on a background thread? Some of Unity API may only be used on the Unity main thread .. not sure if `Application.persistentDataPath` is maybe one of these

Comment: Btw `File.Exists` is completely redundant and only causes FileIO overhead.. `WriteAllText` creates or overwrites the file by default anyway

Comment: @derHugo Thank you for the reply, it is good to know. I will fix the data paths to static readonly not to construct them repeatly.

Comment: @derHugo exactly... It was the mistake. The second code snippet was running on a background thread, this caused the issue. Thank you!
  Maybe someone also have this error and can solve it this way. It is totally meaningful that most of Unity API uses the Unity main thread.
  `Application.persistentDataPath` is one of these.
  I will write an Answer to this Question now.

Comment: @derHugo Makes totally sense with `File.Exists`. Thank you also for you refactoring tipps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the anwer was based on the Help of ***@derHugo*** :

Some of the Unity API is using only the Unity main thread. `Application.persistentDataPath` is one piece of this Unity API elements.
So the **problem was**, that in the **first** code snippet i was using the **Unity Main Thread**, but in the **second** code snippet i used a **Background Thread**. Was really easy to fix. Instead of using another thread, i used:

```
`<myasyncfunction>.ContinueWithOnMainThread(task => {....
    //second code snippet
})`
```

**Refactoring tips** of this Code:

- `File.Exists` can be removed, it is totally redundant. `WriteAllText` creates or overwrites the file by default anyway.
- The Construction of data paths over and over again makes no sense. Better way is to create `public static readonly` paths and use them instead.

Hope the Solution of ***@derHugo*** can help someone else.

Have a nice Day if you read this :)